# Substance painter's PBR metalic material shows black in Aframe

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I'm exporting an object has gltf from substance painter and i'm importing it into my A-frame scene. However, the metallic outer material is shown dark in my current scene and other materials like plastic white are all visible. The scene already has ambient and directional lights. Unable to figure out this behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add an Environment Map to your Metallic Materials, because metals especially shiny ones are mostly reflection. Light entities and ambient light are not sufficient to provide that.